# 'git log' dates incorrect in a GitHub action

Tags: git, github-actions

I'm using this script to generate a file with commit dates

```
cat .github/workflows/header.md > "COVID 19/fechas.md"
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD COVID\ 19/*.csv | while read filename; do
    date=$(git log -1 --format="%aD" -- "$filename")
    echo "| $date  | $filename |" >>  "COVID 19/fechas.md"
done
git config --global user.email "jjmerelo@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "FechaActionBot"
git add "COVID 19/fechas.md"
git commit -m "Fichero de fechas generado"
```

In this [GitHub Action](https://github.com/JJ/datasets/blob/master/.github/workflows/fechas.yml), which checks out the code and runs above as a script.

No matter what I use as format (commiter or author date), I get [the same result](https://github.com/JJ/datasets/blob/master/COVID%2019/fechas.md), which shows the same date (the current one) for all files.

Answer (score 5):

By default, [the `checkout` action does a shallow clone](https://github.com/actions/checkout). You need to configure it for a deep clone, as indicated, if you want to access the real commit date (and not the date of a ghost commit created by the shallow clone), this way:

```
name: genera fechas
on:
  push:
    paths:
    - '**.csv'

jobs:
  genera_fechas:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Genera CSV
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: '0'
      - name: Fechas
        run: .github/workflows/dates.sh
      - name: Check in
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```