# Why does git bundle not work in github action?

Tags: git, github, github-actions, github-release, git-bundle

I have a github action workflow where I want to bundle my repository into a git bundle and then include it in a github release.

The bundling is done with the command,

```
git bundle create my-bundle.bundle --all
```

The bundle gets created correctly but when downloaded from the release page, the bundle cannot be unbundle. Instead I get the following error:

```
git clone .\my-bundle.bundle
Cloning into 'my-bundle'...
Receiving objects: 100% (294/294), 138.15 KiB | 19.73 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (26/26), done.
error: Could not read 53c23e17ab345ff12fd711ae4e8ce49d941fef7a
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 110f058db5ba201d81669b4245709a9b18a813bd
fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
```

I expect `git clone .\my-bundle.bundle` to create a directory called `my-bundle` which includes the whole git repository history.

I have verified that my computer uses the latest git version (the same which the workflow also uses, 2.39.2).

Comment: Try verifying the bundle, `git bundle verify my-bundle.bundle`?

Comment: Hint: because of [shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60869246/7976758).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, GitHub Actions performs a shallow clone, which contains data for a single commit.  This is much faster than cloning the entire repo, and is also cheaper on the server side.

If you don't need the history, then this is a win all around.  However, if you do need the history, like in this case, then you need to indicate that like so:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```